# Cannot reload attributes columns using QGIS

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, editing, table

Unfortunately, I have clicked on the edit button in the attributes table and the spreadsheet with the polygons and their attributes has disappeared (see picture).

How do I make the spreadsheet reappear?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can switch back and forth between the `form` view and the `table` view using the corresponding icons at the lower right of the window

[image]